# Unknown column '' in 'on clause' in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, join

Im trying to do a join query using CodeIgniter activercord class, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('accredited_majors, all_majors_accredited, accredited')
                    ->select('universities.name, universities.slug')
                    ->from('accreditations')
                    ->join('universities', 'universities.id = '.$uni_id)
                    ->where('accreditations.university_id', $uni_id)
                    ->where('accreditations.country', $country)
                    ->get();
```

But im getting this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '820' in 'on clause'

SELECT `accredited_majors`, `all_majors_accredited`, `accredited`, `default_universities`.`name`, `default_universities`.`slug` FROM (`default_accreditations`) JOIN `default_universities` ON `default_universities`.`id` = `820` WHERE `default_accreditations`.`university_id` = '820' AND `default_accreditations`.`country` = 'AE'
```

I believe the error is in the join() line:

```
->join('universities', 'universities.id = '.$uni_id)
```

how can i include a variable in the join() function?

Comment: I think it should be `join('universities', 'universities.id = accreditations.university_id')` instead

Answer (score 2):

in your code u have 2 WHERE clause and not `ON` and your join is wrong with on clause .

try this

```
    $query = $this->db->select('accredited_majors, all_majors_accredited, accredited')
                ->select('universities.name, universities.slug')
                ->from('accreditations')
                ->join('universities', 'universities.id = accreditations.university_id')
                ->where('accreditations.university_id', $uni_id)
                ->where('accreditations.country', $country)
                ->get();
```

Comment: Is there a function called ON() in codeigniter activerecord?
this gave me this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::on()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->select('accredited_majors, all_majors_accredited, accredited')
                    ->select('universities.name, universities.slug')
                    ->from('accreditations')
                    ->join('universities', "universities.id = accreditations.$uni_id" , 'left')
                    ->where('accreditations.university_id', $uni_id)
                    ->where('accreditations.country', $country)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('accredited_majors, all_majors_accredited, accredited')
->select('universities.name, universities.slug')
->from('accreditations')
->join('universities', 'universities.id = accreditations.university_id', 'left')
->where('accreditations.university_id', $uni_id)
->where('accreditations.country', $country)
->group_by('accreditations.university_id')
->get();
```